# How to access a MongoDB database from a different Server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In a microservice architecture, I have 2 separate services with different mongoDb databases. Teacher-Service and Student-service.

Now I'm trying to create a login function, once a user submits an email I'd love to query both databases to determine if the user is either a teacher or a student.

How do I implement this in Node.js using the express framework.

Comment: Do you want to create new Auth-service???

Comment: Nah. To do this I'll have to refactor 70% of the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can make HTTP requests to both services (synchronous communication).
For e.g. `GET http://teachers.service.com/api/users?email=<input-email>` and `GET http://students.service.com/api/users?email=<input-email>` with some auth header with mind of course :).

Or another way to communicate through services is using asynchronous communication transporters like `RabbitMQ`, `Kafka`, `NATS` and so on. You can search for their documentations to get ground up.